# What plugin(s) are best for this User registration task?

Tags: plugins, login, user-registration, signup

I have a site with user registration and I have a few specific qualifications that I must fulfill.

1. The login/registration area should be on its own page within the template using a custom page template (im going to use jquery tabs for login/reg); i dont want to use the regular wordpress signup/login page.
2. I must be able to add extra fields to the registration process (phone, address, etc)
3. I'm already using simple facebook/twitter connect so that's taken care of, but it should be compatible with that (although i dont see that as a problem as it seems to take care of everything separately)
4. it needs ability for captcha

Comment: When you say "compatible with [facebook/twitter], what do you mean?

Comment: "simple facebook connect" and "simple twitter connect". im pretty sure it should be fine, but it would probably be better if it doesnt create an entirely new table for users, or somehow hooks into the existing users table, as I'm assuming facebook/twitter login widgets work alongside the default users table. i could be wrong, it was just a guess

Comment: Ok, so basically you just want a custom login page, with extra fields, with an added captcha?

Comment: correct. im not sure how hard it is as well but it would be nice to have a custom 'profile page' as well where it just shows the data they entered and allows them to update their email, name, and other fields. nothing fancy, just pretty damn simple. i just basically never want them to see the absolutely miserable backend of wordpress dashboard, and instead just see something custom. i looked at buddypress but it seems so complicated, i really am trying to make this pretty simple

Comment: BuddyPress may be overkill depending on your sites needs (It creates a bunch of new tables). I use their Registration Fields plugin which allows you to define additional fields and JOINS with the default user table. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-registration-options/. It's really not complicated. But it sounds like you want to make the profile and registration experience unique to your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) is a premium one, but was the only one that solved without flaws a custom registration I needed to implement...

Appart from the *Premium* part, I have to inform that only the *Developer* licence will give you access to the **User Registration** extension.

If you go past the Premium-Developer issue, check their forums as there's a glitch with the *nickname* when registering users.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin called [WC Address fields on User Registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-afour/) that's not long come out. It might help with adding the fields you need.

I needed to add name & address fields to the user registration form on a WooCommerce site and the free version did exactly what I needed, but there's also a premium version available for a good price that lets you add more fields and change text etc.